# Unable to write gps location to exif

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude, exif

I have an app that gets the location of the user using LocationManager and tries to write that data into the Exif Data of an image. For some reason the value never gets written and the location remains null. Here is my function for writing to the Exif and converting the Latitude and Longitude :

```
 public void geoTag(String filename){
    ExifInterface exif;

    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filename);
        int num1Lat = (int)Math.floor(latitude);
        int num2Lat = (int)Math.floor((latitude - num1Lat) * 60);
        double num3Lat = (latitude - ((double)num1Lat+((double)num2Lat/60))) * 3600000;

        int num1Lon = (int)Math.floor(longitude);
        int num2Lon = (int)Math.floor((longitude - num1Lon) * 60);
        double num3Lon = (longitude - ((double)num1Lon+((double)num2Lon/60))) * 3600000;

        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, /*num1Lat+"/1,"+num2Lat+"/1,"+num3Lat+"/1000"*/);
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, num1Lon+"/1,"+num2Lon+"/1,"+num3Lon+"/1000");


        if (latitude > 0) {
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "N"); 
        } else {
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "S");
        }

        if (longitude > 0) {
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "E");    
        } else {
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "W");
        }

        exif.saveAttributes();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("PictureActivity", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } 

    }
```

In my current position the latitude and longitude values are approx 40.42 and -81.92

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
int num1Lat = (int)Math.floor(latitude);
int num2Lat = (int)Math.floor((latitude - num1Lat) * 60);
int num3Lat = (int)Math.floor((latitude - num1Lat - ((double)num2Lat)/60) * 3600);

int num1Lon = (int)Math.floor(longitude);
int num2Lon = (int)Math.floor((longitude - num1Lon) * 60);
int num3Lon = (int)Math.floor((longitude - num1Lon - ((double)num2Lon)/60) * 3600);

exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, num1Lat+"/1,"+num2Lat+"/1,"+num3Lat+"/1");
exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, num1Lon+"/1,"+num2Lon+"/1,"+num3Lon+"/1");
```

This code worked for me. For example, one of my EXIF tags (Latitude) showed "37/1,53/1,42/1", which corresponded to 37.895 degrees